# Smallest field extension of $ℚ$ that is closed under $\exp$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, exponential-function, computability

Let $F$ be a field such that $ℚ \leq F \leq ℝ$. Let $G = F(\pi,i)$. I want to define $\exp$ function on $G$. It must satisfy that:

1. $\forall x,y \in G \space \exp (x + y) = \exp x \times \exp y$
2. $\exp 0 = 1$
3. **Periodicity and Positiveness:** $\exp \pi i = -1$ and $\neg \exists x \in G \cap [0, \pi) \space \exp xi = -i$
4. **Existence of Logarithm:** $\forall x \in G^\times \space \exists y \in G \space \exp y = x$

My questions are:

1. Is $\exp$ uniquely defined by above?
2. What is the smallest such $F$?
3. Is the smallest such $F$ computably enumerable?
4. Given an oracle that computes $\exp$, is $\log$ a computable function (if not nessesarily assuming a branch cut)?
5. What is an example of a computable number that is not in $G$?

Comment: I think you want $-1$, not $-i$, in 3.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Giving it $-1$ only ensures that the period is $2\pi i$. Giving it $-i$ also ensures positiveness. (or should I say 'counterclockwiseness'?)

Comment: Your function is $e^{ax}$ with $a=\pm 1$. Let $F_0 = \Bbb{Q}, F_{n+1}=F_n(\exp(F_n), \log(F_n))$. There is no simpler description of your field. At first it is not obvious which of those expressions are well-defined (maybe $\frac1{e^2-3=0}=\infty$ who knows ?) so we need the theorem on the algebraic (in)dependence of $e^{c_1},\ldots,e^{c_m},c_1,\ldots,c_m$.

Comment: @reuns, it's unclear what $c_1, \ldots, c_m$ are. One could let $c_2 = \log c_1$.